# How to track GPS data from Android Mobile?

Tags: java, android, gps, google-earth

I've started to learn about Micro. Now I'm tracking GPS data. I would like to use information from Google Earth about the position in order to make a calendar. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Android has a LocationManager service to enable this kind of thing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

To be honest though this will be quite tricky if you're just starting to learn. I would look for basic Android tutorials, try to follow those, then move onto tutorials about LocationManager when you've learned the ropes.